# setAuthConfig() vs setAuthConfigFile() in the Google OAuth2.0 API

Tags: google-oauth

While reading the online **Google OAuth2.0** documentation, I have seen:

**This**:

`$client->setAuthConfigFile('secret_keys.json');`

**And this**:

`$client->setAuthConfig('secret_keys.json');`

They are being used in the same situations and I would like to know if there is any difference between them, or if I shall stick to use one of them always.

Answer (score 3):

Use `setAuthConfig`.

`setAuthConfigFile` is now just an alias for backwards compatibility and is deprecated.

`setAuthConfigFile` just calls `setAuthConfig`

Refer to this. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php and search for `public function setAuthConfigFile($file)`